# Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'mc', but it was: a custom ln object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));
    const querySnapshot = getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
   });
}, []);
```

I'm trying to access all documents from my firestore collection.
but it throws an error **FirebaseError: Expected type 'mc', but it was: a custom ln object**

Comment: Can you share your complete code so we can see where you are importing those functions from? I doubt you are importing `query()` from Realtime DB SDK `"firebase/database"` and not Firestore `"firebase/firestore"` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put `await` in getDocs (or `then`). Then you should use an async function that is called inside `useEffect` and not directly call it inside `useEffect`.

Something like this should work:

```
const myFunction = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
}

useEffect(() => {
   myFunction();
}, []);
```